# Order has discount but the discount was not applied in the item level

Tags: magento2, sales-order, discount, sales, bug

Can someone help me understand why my order has a discount but the discount is not divided into each of the items accordingly. In most of the orders, the discount amount is divided into each item accordingly but this order is not and there's around 3 or more orders like this.
Is this a known Magento bug? Or it's just how it is.
Thank you!
[image: See image attached]

Answer (score 0):

When Cart price rule applied ideally it is visible in order discount colum. Magento 2.3.1 its showing discount amount. Please share how you have created Cart Price Rules.

[image]